# Automate pasting of multiple images on customised PowerPoint layout

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, powerpoint

I would like to paste 100 set of unique images (set of 3 per slide) into a single PowerPoint slide, presented as shown in the screenshot below. I have already created a slide master with the respective placeholders positioning.

Is there a way to automate the inserting of the images into the placeholders without having to do so one by one? As I have 100 set of 3 images, doing it manually means I have to insert them 300 times, which is extremely time consuming.

[This is a screenshot of my intended outcome. The output should be 100 slides with unique set of 3 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezs8R.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So you need a loop that creates 100 slides, each from the master. On each slide you need to navigate to each of the three placeholders. And at each placeholder you need to select he relevant image and add it. (Just trying to understand the problem and sketch the shape of the solution.)